# Two weeks after interview. Do I still have a chance?

Tags: interviewing

So I had a preliminary first round phone interview with a company I really liked. I thought the phone interview went well.

I waited for a week, and I did not hear back from them. So I started to worry and emailed the interviewer to follow up with the initial interview, and he replied 5 minutes later with

"I enjoyed speaking with you as well.  We’re still circling up internally to figure out next steps.  Apologies for the delay, it’s just been a busy couple weeks.  I’ll let you know as soon as I have an update."

Now its been a week after my follow-up email and 2 weeks from the first round interview, and I still have not heard back from them. I am assuming at this point, I probably did not make it to the second round.

I was never given a timeline for when they would respond back by.

Comment: "I am assuming at this point, I probably did not make it to the second round." - why? Use this time to pursue other openings. If this one contacts you, great. If not, you'll soon have other places to follow-up with.

Comment: When I was rejected, I always heard from the corresponding company, typically by receiving a formal rejection mail. If you did not hear anything, chances are high that they simply did not reach a decision yet.

Comment: Most companies in my experience don't let you know if you have not been chosen. At any rate, what does it matter? They will contact you if you are still in the running. You should continue to pursue other opportunities and not wait for one to come through. So what is the actual problem with not having heard?  I have heard back from companies months later because they had a hiring freeze or the hiring official went out on sick leave or they just have a horrendous process, so you never know when is too long. But just keep looking and it doesn't matter when they get back to you.

Comment: Just because you haven't heard back does not mean you are not still a candidate. Sometimes there are internal delays that have nothing, and I mean absolutely nothing, to do with the candidate, position, department or otherwise. We are currently going through our budget process. Calling back sales rep candidates is not always on the top of the list and will be pushed aside until the spreadsheet nightmare has ended. If you are truly interested contact them again and tell them you are very interested in the position.

Comment: With my first job out of school I didn't hear back from one company for over two weeks, but still got an offer - turns out the hiring team really was just busy. However, definitely keep interviewing so all your eggs are not in one basket. Hopefully they'll let you know either way, but don't let it keep you from moving forwards with other opportunities. (And if you do have other offers or deadlines, this is a good time to let them know.)